# Unable to Invoke SqlInfoMessageEventHandler

Tags: delegates

I am trying to invoke the `SqlInfoMessageEventHandler`, but not able to. Can anyone please help? Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnect = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DEV_ENV;Data Source=SQL15");

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE", sqlConnect))
        {
            sqlConnect.Open();
            sqlConnect.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(MessageEventHandler);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    static void MessageEventHandler(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not able to." What happens?

Comment: When I keep a debug point on the Console.Writeline, it is not hitting.